# Why is child table view controller unresponsive to touches and scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a basic view controller with the following code:

```
class List2ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDummyViewController), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func showDummyViewController(){

        let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tableController")
          if let controller = controller {
             controller.view.frame = view.bounds
             view.addSubview(controller.view)
             addChildViewController(controller)
             controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am adding a child view controller that happens to be table view controller. The code for this table view controller is as follows:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nib = UINib(nibName: CustomCellTypeIdentifiers.NoResultCell, bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomCellTypeIdentifiers.NoResultCell)

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCellTypeIdentifiers.NoResultCell, for: indexPath) as! CellType
        return cell
    }

}
```

My problem is that when my table view is added as a child controller, it is not responsive to any touch inputs. The table view shows up but it does not scroll through or select any rows. Additionally, my cells do not show up in rows. Can you please explain to what I am missing in this implementation? Thank you in advance.

Heres a picture of the result: [image]

Comment: Check is your tableView userIntractionEnabled.

Comment: Check in debug view hierarchy if the cells are being created. You maybe haven't set the dataSource and delegates for the tableView?

Comment: @Rikh its a standard table view controller from the storyboard so the data source and delegate are automatically set up for you. And yes the cells are being created.

Comment: @Joe Yes the table view is user interaction enabled.

Comment: I see you have MKMapKit, but I don't know did you implement any code for mapkit. It is possible that your mapView is on top of your table view.

Comment: @PakHoCheung Thank you for your  comment. The portion of screen occupied by the child view controller is "controlled" by the child view controller. That is what these lines are for: addChildViewController(controller), controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self). And no the mapView is not causing the problem.

Comment: Did your delagate and datasource methods called ? I have doubt that it is not called

Comment: @chiragshah So the problems were the data source and the delegate methods, which is odd because anytime you drag a standard table view controller from the storyboard library the data source and the delegate is automatically set up to the corresponding class in the identity inspector. On the storyboard I  double checked the outlet for the tableview's delegate and data source and there were two yellow triangles beside them which I have never seen before so I disconnected the delegate and data source and reconnected them again and my problem went away. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that i see here:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCellTypeIdentifiers.NoResultCell, for: indexPath)
```

should be like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCellTypeIdentifiers.NoResultCell, for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCellName
```

where `CustomTableViewCellName` should be replaced by the value of `CustomCellTypeIdentifiers.NoResultCell` i.e. your custom cell name, as i.e. your nibName also:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: CustomCellTypeIdentifiers.NoResultCell, bundle: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was a careless mistake on my part. I fixed it and downcast the cell to the cell class name. However, the table view remains empty and unresponsive to any row selection and scrolls.

Comment: Have you specified the class name to the UItableviewcontroller added to storyboard as MyTableViewController